# Exit TcpLIstener.AcceptTcpClient() after determined time

Tags: c#, tcplistener, tcpserver

I want my server to stop listening after minute without connection request.
The problem is that after command AcceptTcpClient() it gets into a loop without option to stop it.
There is an option to do that?

```
private static void Listen(TcpListener listener)
    {
        //Start listening
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...\n");

        //Accept connection
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        //Need to stop it after 1 minute.

        listener.Stop();
        //CHECK
        Console.WriteLine("Accepted the connection\n");

        ClientHandle(client);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it:

**1) Asynchronous wait without blocking a thread:**

```
private static async Task Listen(TcpListener listener)
{
    //Start listening
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...\n");

    //Accept connection
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

    await Task.Delay(60000); // async wait for 1 minute

    listener.Stop();
    //CHECK
    Console.WriteLine("Accepted the connection\n");

    ClientHandle(client);
}
```

Do not forget to await this method from caller:

```
await Listen(yourListener);
```

**2) Use `Timer (System.Threading.Timer)`:**

```
private static void Listen(TcpListener listener)
{        
    //Start listening
    listener.Start();

    var timerTimer = new Timer((state) => { listener.Stop(); }, null, 60000, Timeout.Infinite);

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...\n");

    //Accept connection
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

    //CHECK
    Console.WriteLine("Accepted the connection\n");

    ClientHandle(client);
}
```

You can also use any other timer.

Answer (score -1):

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(......);
TcpClient client = null;
int timeout = 30000;//30 sec
server.Start();
using(CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
{
    using(tokenSource.Token.Register(() => server.Stop()))
    {
       client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
       //don't code here, need dispose Token.Register if Accept success
    }
}
//todo here
```

Comment: Why down vote? This is same as `Timer` in `Roman Doskoch`  comment